# I'm getting a white page in a prod server with cake 3

Tags: cakephp-3.0

My Cakephp 3 website is working well with Wamp, and when i transfer my website to my server i'm getting a white page.

My histing said that that the url rewriting is activated on my server, so i guess it's a problem with one of ny htaccess file.

http://www.project-heberg.fr (my domain)

My htaccess :

```
IndexIgnore .htaccess */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*

<Limit GET POST>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from all
</Limit>
<Limit PUT DELETE>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Limit>
AuthName project-heberg.fr
```

http://www.project-heberg.fr/perles (where my cakephp 3 app is)

My htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Have you tried to use the `RewriteBase` directive ? http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#apache Also do you have access to Apache error logs ? Useful information should be inside.

Comment: Hi, i don't access to Apage error logs, i read the documentation but in my case how can i implement the RewriteBase and in which htacess ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you may not have [the requirements](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#requirements) on your production server.

Requirements:

> - HTTP Server. For example: Apache. Having mod_rewrite is preferred, but by no means required.
> - PHP 5.4.16 or greater.
> - mbstring extension
> - intl extension

Please check or ask the host admin regarding the requirements on your prod server. I also faced the white page issue and i found this problem.

Hope this may help. Thanks

Comment: Hi, If you think and it helps you can mark it as correct